# How change style of Paper of Select Materia ui

Tags: material-ui

I tried to change the style of paper in Select, but only can of global Paper:

```
MuiPaper: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              border: "1px solid red",
            },
          },
        },
```

Is posible only change Select Paper? Like this?

```
          MuiSelect: {
        MuiPaper: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              border: "1px solid red",
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by using the `MenuProps` like the example bellow

```
    <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value="10"
          label="Age"
          MenuProps={{
            PaperProps: {
              sx: {
                border: '1px solid red',
              },
            },
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
```